# Getting sum of rows based on column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to sum of values of one column group by another column.
e.g

```
Month     Count
Jan         5
Jan         7
Feb         1
Feb         2
```

I want

```
Month     Count   Status
Jan         5       A
Jan         7       B
Jan        12      SUM
Feb         1       A
Feb         2       B
Feb         3      SUM
```

Comment: Where do the status 'A' and 'B' come from? These doesn't exist in the original table. If you had a third record in January, what should be its status? 'C'? And what about the status of the 10000th record?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is with `rollup`.  However, because you want the original data, this approach does a "fake" aggregation by rownum for the rollup:

```
select Month, sum(Count),
       (case when rn is null then 'SUM' end) as status
from (select rownum as rn, t.*
      from t
     ) t
group by Month, rollup(rn)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the `A` and `B` in the status column.

Answer (score 1):

The original table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    month CHAR(3), 
    num INT,
    status CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO test (month, num, status) VALUES
    ('Jan', 5, 'A'),
    ('Jan', 7, 'B'),
    ('Feb', 1, 'A'),
    ('Feb', 2, 'B');
```

The query:

```
SELECT month, sum(num) AS num, 'SUM' AS status
FROM test
GROUP BY month
UNION
SELECT month, num, status
FROM test
ORDER BY month DESC, status
```

Result:

```
MONTH   NUM   STATUS
Jan     5     A
Jan     7     B
Jan     12    SUM
Feb     1     A
Feb     2     B
Feb     3     SUM
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8980e/2) is the SQLfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select month, sum(count) from table group by rollup(month, count);
```

It will give net total as well, if you want to avoid it use month is not null.

Comment: This assumes the counts are different within a month.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should number it and rollup based on it as you did. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle have `MODEL` clause for the above:
If you've the column status in your table, you have simple query:

[Model Clause Link Oracle Documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/sqlmodel.htm)

```
SELECT month, count , status
FROM my_test2
MODEL
PARTITION BY (MONTH)
DIMENSION BY (status)
MEASURES(count)
RULES(COUNT['Sum'] = count['A']+ count['B'])
order by month desc, status;


MONTH                     COUNT STATUS             
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
Jan                           5 A                    
Jan                           7 B                    
Jan                          12 Sum                  
Feb                           1 A                    
Feb                           2 B                    
Feb                           3 Sum                  

 6 rows selected
```